# Vaadin Focus Color

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Is there are global way to deactivate the focus color? As you can see in the attachment?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Thomas

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That border is the "focus ring" (it's an **accessibility feature** that indicates that the field has received focus *from a keyboard interaction*, but it won't display when focusing the field by using the mouse).

How the focus-ring is styled, depends on each component and theme.

For instance, the focus-ring of TextField in Lumo is a CSS `box-shadow` in the `input-field` part:

```
:host([focus-ring]) [part="input-field"] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--lumo-primary-color-50pct);
}

:host([invalid][focus-ring]) [part="input-field"] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--lumo-error-color-50pct);
}
```

A handy way to find those styles is inspecting the `<style>` tag in the component's shadow DOM
[image: vaadin-text-field shadow DOM]

You can override the focus-ring of vaadin-text-field with

```
:host([focus-ring]) [part="input-field"] {
  box-shadow: none !important
}
```

Then, you [import the stylesheet](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/importing-style-sheets) with a `@CssImport` with `themeFor="vaadin-text-field"` or by means of `registerStyles`.

Comment: Another recommended way of importing component style sheets today is with a custom theme (since V19 and V14.6): https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/custom-theme/#vaadin-component-styles

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explenations! I have one further short question: Is there a global way to do this for all components (text field, combobox, ...) and for the complete application? Maybe in the styles.css where I also have my general colors (e. g. "--lumo-primary-color")?

Comment: No, because the default focus-ring is based on theme colors (that are also used for styling other things), and every component applies the style differently. However, many components use vaadin-text-field internally (combobox, date picker, etc) thus the fix for text field should also apply to them,